# how to remove the margins from the vue site

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I would like to remove the margins from my site so I don't get the scroll bars, but I can't, I've tried margin 0 and padding 0, but it still didn't work.

[as you can see, it has margins on the top and on the left and the scroll bars are on the bottom and on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObGfJ.png)

my code:

```
<template>
<div>
</div>
</template>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly, one last question, how to centralize all items? and then I close the question.

Comment: There are many way to align content. You can align horizontally or vertically or both. For example you can use flex or css grid (`display: flex;` or `display.grid;`) then align horizontally with `justify-content: center;` and vertically with `align-items: center;`

Comment: You can learn more at this links [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)